# Return last match of matchstr within single line

Tags: regular-expression, matchlist

I have a little class/function detector in my `.vimrc` displaying, in my statusline, the python class/function my cursor currently is inside of. I am currently trying to adapt it for C++ source files, and am running into a pretty simple (?) regex (?) problem.

My function essentially works as follows:

1. find the line number of the previous match of `::`, but ignore `std` or `cout`:

```
let prev_class_line_number = search('\(std\)\@<!::\(cout\)\@!', 'bncW')
```

2. From that line, return the \word before `::`:

```
let classname = matchstring(getline(prev_class_line_number), '\(\w\+\)::')
```

For example, within the following code block:

```cpp
void MyClass::setSomething(int input) {
   // ...
}
```

my function returns "MyClass" (yay!).

I however run into issues with this type of code:

```cpp
std::vector<int> MyClass::doSomethingElse(){
   // ...
}
```

where my function returns `std` instead of `MyClass`.

I spent a good amount of time getting my line-number-detection regexp to work (specifically, to not match `std::` or `::cout`), but I can't figure out how to get my second regexp to return 'MyClass'.

This looks like an incredibly simple problem and I'm sure I've been missing something. I searched into `\zs`/`\ze`, negative/positive lookahead/lookbehind, `matchlist`, but I haven't figured the right combination yet.

How do I extract the first word before a `::` instance who is not `std`?

**tl;dr: given the line `std::foo bar::baz()`, how can I return `bar` but not `std`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect solution is probably difficult to find in case of template class but for "simple" case maybe:

```
^\(\S\+\s\+\)\?\(\w\+\)::\(\~\?\w\+\)\ze(
```

The first bit: `^\(\S\+\s+\)?` match the return type if any (assuming it doesn't contain a space. For constructor and destructor you may have no return type and that is why we make it optional (`\?`)

The second bit: `\(\w\+\)` match the class name.

The third bit: `::\(\~\?\w\+\)\ze(` match the method name.

The `\ze(` force the expression to match till the first parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry my first version lack the `\ze(` that forces the expression to search the parenthesis and makes that you can match the return type as the first word `\S\+` (for "simple" case)

Comment: Oooooh but that's even better if I use that with `matchlist` because I get in ONE SINGLE regexp both the class and function !? Thanks !

Comment: You are Welcome :-). If the solution fit the need don't forget to validate it ;-)